# function continuous from the strong topology to the weak topology

Tags: analysis, continuity

Let $X$ be reflexive Banach space, $F$ a function of $X$ into $X$ such that $F(u)=u+TN(u)$ where $T$ is linear and $N$ is nonlinear. Is $F(u)$ continuous from strong topology to weak topology? How can prove that?

Comment: Welcome to MSE. It will be more likely that you will get an answer if you show us that you made an effort. This should be added to the question rather than in the comments.

Comment: What assumption(s) are you making on $N$?.

Comment: $N$ is just nonlinear

Comment: please some one answer me